# Dependency updates do not appear after browserify

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify

My project has many dependencies and I use browserify to bundle them. Now I modify a file from one dependency under `node_modules/`, but the updates doesn't appear in the generated js file.

I'm pretty new to browserify and I'd like to know what do I miss?

Comment: How did you know that dependencies are not updated? Do you look inside generated file? If you are checking updates in the browser, it can just be cached.

Comment: @azaviruha Yes I checked the file generated.

Comment: how do you bundle them? are you using seperate bundles?